# How to Delete all history that contains only one word in Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome, I have a history of a certain word (Like Google). 
I want to delete it. Please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got Answer, In History search `Word (Like Google)` you want to delete, check mark the first item you want to delete and scroll to the bottom and hold down the `SHIFT` key on your keyboard and click the last item. All items are now checked and click removed selected items.

Answer (score 0):

You have a search bar above history. Type there for example "youtube" and you can mark all youtube history to be deleted

Comment: mark all option is not available in Google Chrome.

Comment: @RameshR  Click for search result ( check it ) then hold CTRL and go to the bottom and click the last element and BAM all are selected